# Extra Argument In A Call

Tags: swift, syntax, call

I get the following error since I upgraded to Xcode 8:

> Extra Argument In A Call

My code looks like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, link).validate().responseJSON { response in
```

The error highlights `link` in red. It is defined further above the code:

```
let link = "http://www.gov.je/_layouts/15/C5.Gov.Je.CarParks/proxy.aspx"
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Are you using swift 3 and Alamofire 4.0?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I think I have, it says version 4.0.1

Comment: yes. I am using Alamofire 4.0.1 and I think I am using swift 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [document](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#data-request---simple-with-url-string):

> - Data Request - Simple with URL string
>
> ```
> // Alamofire 3
>
> Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).response { request, response, data, error in
>     print(request)
>     print(response)
>     print(data)
>     print(error)
> }
>
> // Alamofire 4
>
> Alamofire.request(urlString).response { response in // method defaults to `.get`
>     debugPrint(response)
> }
> ```

So you need to remove `.GET` argument

Answer (score 0):

```
  let link = "http://www.gov.je/_layouts/15/C5.Gov.Je.CarParks/proxy.aspx"
    Alamofire.request(link).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
```